# CoffeeScript:: I don't know why return function body when using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, coffeescript

I'm new to Coffeescript, and I have a question about Ajax.

```
jQuery ->
  api = 
    getId: ->
      res  = []
      $.ajax
        dataType: "jsonp"
        url: "http://localhost:3004/videos.json"
        success: (data) =>
          if data
            data.forEach (elem) =>
              embed_id = elem.video_id
              res.push(embed_id)
            console.log res
            return res
```

I try this code, then

```
console.log res
```

the output is

```
["id1","id2","id3",...] .
```

So I expect `api.getId()` to return `["id1","id2","id3",...]`
Instead, I see

```
Object 
  -> abort
    function(a) {...}
  ...
  -> status: 200
  ...
  -> success: function (){...}
```

in my debug window.

I want to return the value of the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return res` statement is inside AJAX call. It **does not** return from `getId()` function, but inner AJAX callback. You cannot do this like this. AJAX calls are asynchronous, while you want them do be synchronous. I would advice you to do something like this:

```
jQuery ->
  api = 
    getId: (callback) ->
      res  = []
      $.ajax
        dataType: "jsonp"
        url: "http://localhost:3004/videos.json"
        success: (data) =>
          if data
            data.forEach (elem) =>
              embed_id = elem.video_id
              res.push(embed_id)
            callback(res)
          else
            callback(null)
        error: =>
          callback(null)
```

and now in code you can use

```
api.getId(function(res) {
  // do something with the result.
});
// some other things
```

Keep in mind that the `some other things` code may (and will) be called before the `do something with the result` code.

Sorry about mixing CoffeeScript with JavaScript but I'm not really into CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a Coffeescript problem, this is just how asynchronous requests work. You cannot immediately return the result from the XHR call, you have to define a callback that get receive the result (or the error) once that call completes.

Take a look at what your code compiles to (as Javascript).

```
getId: ->
   ## .. snip ..
   $.ajax ## .. snip ..
```

You have a function `getId`, which returns the return value of `$.ajax`, which is (according to the jQuery spec) an XHR object, not the result of the success callback. You could use it to check on the progress, abort the request, set more options and so on.

```
success: (data) =>
      ## .. snip ..
      return res
```

There is no point in returning anything from an XHR success callback. You need to work with the data right here, for example putting it into the DOM somewhere, or calling another function that does something useful with it.